Permission Denied Error When Accessing Firestore in Secondary Firebase Project in Flutter
I have a Flutter app that is set up with two Firebase projects:
Project A (default): Used for authentication (OAuth) and Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).
Project B (secondary): Used for storing customer-specific data.
I’m running into an issue with Firestore security rules in Project B. Here’s the setup:

Authentication is handled by Firebase Project A.
Customer data is stored in Firebase Project B.

Problem:
When I set this rule on Project B, it works (I'm able to fetch data):
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow anyone to read/write for a limited time
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2025, 10, 27);
    }
  }
}

But when I change the Firestore rule to require authentication, I get this error:
[cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

Here is the rule that fails:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow authenticated users to read/write
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

What I've Tried:
I verified that the Firebase App initialization is working correctly for Project B.
I’m able to fetch documents from Project B when using the open rule (with a date condition), but not when using the authenticated rule (request.auth != null).
The user is properly authenticated via Project A.
Question:
Why does the permission get denied when I use request.auth != null in Project B's rules? Is there a specific way I should handle Firebase authentication and security rules for multiple Firebase projects in a Flutter app?
